# Android viewpager weight - Fullscreen Theme

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need help with viewpager.

I have two linear layouts and they are seprating my main view to 2 rows. I want to add viewpager to first row but it covers whole page when theme is full screen.

Waiting for your help. Thanks

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <widgets.Header
        android:id="@+id/headerWidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </widgets.Header>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: could you please post your complete xml code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you xml code as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomePage" >
    <Widgets.Header
        android:id="@+id/headerWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >
    </Widgets.Header>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note :**

I don't know why setting `layout_height` to `0dp` in `ViewPager` with FullScreen Theme doesn't render the `layout_weight` correctly. When the `layout_height` of `ViewPager` is set to some `dp` (say 1dp) but not `match_parent` or `wrap_content` works great.

Comment: Thank Sankar. But it doesn't work. Viewpager is still covering whole page. I think there is a bug at Android ViewPager

Comment: And i need another control over ViewPager. So i need 2 linearlayouts in main linearlayout.

Comment: really?? I am sure that ViewPager and LinearLayout each occupies 50% of the screen. which version of Android you are running? device or emulator?

Comment: Android 3.0 , i am using emulator but design tool shows incorrect,too. this picture shows what i want.. http://i.imgur.com/7Jh5MHN.png?1  Thank you

Comment: am clear now.wait i vl check it. update your question clearly. so others can find it easily

Comment: Hey i don't know what the problem is? May be a bug. But when the `layout_height` of `ViewPager` is set to some `dp` (say 1dp) but not `match_parent` or `wrap_content` its works fine. Check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, there isn't any problem when setting dp. but setting dp is not good solution for different screen sizes. Thanks